# Drag and drop from gef viewer to editor

Tags: eclipse, drag-and-drop, scroll, figure, eclipse-gef

I have a ScrollingGraphicalViewer containing a list of figures, let's call them "group figures", representing some business objects with relations between them. Each "group figure" may contain some other figures which are related. There are edit parts for every "group figure".

I want to be able to drag and drop any figure from the viewer into another editor. Right now, the viewer has a drag listener extending an AbstractTransferDragSourceListener class. Inside the listener, we get the viewer selection which is a corresponding EditPart of the selected group figure.

When there are many figures in the viewer and the vertical scrolling appears, I'm not able to detect the exact figure I dragged, based on the drag event and figure coordinates. How can I obtain the dragged figure?

Answer (score 1):

There is a GEF tutorial on DnD. Here is is: https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-GEF-dnd/GEF-dnd.html
You can assume that you're dragging selected editparts I guess. Also you should set the transfer data for DnDing staff outside the viewer. The transfer data should most likely be the model object or image of the figure.
If you're DnDing not selected editparts then you'd have to figure out what exactly you're dragging from the mosule location coordinates at the drag start. Use viewer's

```
#findObjectAtExcluding(Point location, Collection exclusionSet, Conditional conditional)
```

method to find editpart under mouse. From the found editpart you can either get or the figure to set the appropriate transfer data.